# Group by week day

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

have this portion of a large table T;

```
+---------------+------------+
| session_id    | visit_time       |
+---------------+------------+
| 4f89cebc109f9 | 1334431476 |
| 4f89cf283d21c | 1334431528 |
| 4f89cf283d21c | 1334431534 |
| 4f89cf3b350a6 | 1334431547 |
| 4f89cf42ab640 | 1334431554 |
+---------------+------------+
```

I want to find number of session_id weekday-wise. Session_id is not primary key. So I tried:

```
select count(distinct(session_id)) from T group by weekday(from_unixtime(time))
```

But it won't work because if same `session_id` has `visit_time` on two different sundays, then it counts them as `1`, although it rightly counts 1 when same `session_id` has `visit_time` on same sunday.

The expected thing is :  I want to know how many session-ids have visit day as sun, mon etc. If a session_id has visited on two different sundays, then they are counted twice, but if on same sunday, then only 1 count. 
So how can I do it in Mysql ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you wanna get for result... group by week, weekday ?

Comment: Have a look at DATE_FORMAT

Comment: According to your sentence "I want to find number of session_id weekday-wise", the expected result "if same session_id has visit_time on two different sundays", is 1 for that `session_id`. Do you want to find number of `session_id` day-wise?

Comment: @oswald: No, Basically I want to know how many session-ids have visit day as sun, mon etc. Now expected is : if a session_id has visited on two different sundays, then they are counted twice, but if on same sunday, then only 1 count.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `WEEK` instead of `WEEKDAY`

```
SELECT  WEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(time)) WeekNo,
        DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(time),'%a') WeekName,
        COUNT(DISTINCT(session_id)) 
FROM    T 
GROUP   BY WEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(time)),
           DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(time),'%a')
```

- [WEEK](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week)